# Add Fixed Width file to PDF

Tags: c#, pdf

I have a client that is asking me to add a fixed width (510 character) header record to a PDF file.  They have asked that I create a new page (not problem) in which I write this fixed width header record on.

I can do this, and see the header record as page 1, followed by the original PDF.  The problem is white space.  The 510 character fixed width header is about 60% white space and all the ways I've tried generating the PDF cause this to be truncated. There are also line breaks where the text wraps.  The client want to be able to use some OCR software they have purchased in order to read this header file from page 1.

I know very little about PDF file format.  I've tried using ABCpdf, PDFsharp, and also created an RDLC and bound it to this header string and then generated a PDF from that.  All 3 resulted in the same outcome.

Let me say I know how crazy this sounds, but it's what a client is requesting. I proposed several other ways in which we could solve their problem, but this (right now) is the only one they are comfortable with.  They are not comfortable with me just appending the 510 characters onto the byte array, and having them separate it out programatically.

Comment: I don't really understand your requirement. Can you provide an example? One thing is clear, though: hoping to read an accurate number of consecutive white spaces using OCR is most likely futile.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to have a page displaying the long header?  You can create a PDF page of any size (Print to PDF with a custom pages size of 20" wide by 6" tall.  Weird but possible.)

Once that page is created, it can be inserted into another document of regular letter size pages.

Are you looking for consecutive pages displaying chunks of the header?

Answer (score 0):

Using an OCR to read content that you put in is an overkill. Instead of rendering the 500-character header as text. Render it as single-character form fields. This way it will be easy to access those form-fields by name and retrieve the values using the same PDF library which you created the PDFs.